# Not sure how to enable this if and else statement to reveal the correct string

Tags: python, if-statement, random

When I run this bit of code here, the resulting string is random, and doesn't adhere to the rules I laid out for it. Is there a better way to format this statement for it to run properly?

```
import random
for x in range(1):
  print random.randint(1,8)

if random.randint(1,8) in {1, 2, 3}:
  print("https://media.giphy.com/media/vgPDmpQsQsjug/giphy.gif")

elif random.randint(1,8) in {4, 5, 6}:
  print("http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/676/205/57b.gif")

else:
  print("Bye")
```

Comment: Each call to `randint` is giving you a new random number

Comment: You might want to consider setting the output of `random.randint` to a variable and use that in the `if` statement.

Comment: `for x in range(0,1)` you mean?

Comment: What is `for x in range(1):` doing there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.randint` calculates a new random number each time it is called. In addition, you don't need a `for` loop to print a variable.

Instead, call `random.randint` once, store the number in a variable, then reuse in subsequent logic. You may also wish to utilize `range`, e.g. `if x in range(1, 4)` represents clearer logic than `if x in {1, 2, 3}`.

```
x = random.randint(1, 8) 

if x in range(1, 4):
    print("https://media.giphy.com/media/vgPDmpQsQsjug/giphy.gif")

elif x in range(4, 7):
    print("http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/676/205/57b.gif")

else:
    print("Bye")
```

Stylistically, you should adhere to the "4-character indent" rule. Although your code is not incorrect, it's not consistent with commonly used conventions.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this `random` also has `random.choice` which will allow to select on of your choices randomly not needing to generate an `int` to compare.  There is also `random.choices` which accepts an argument that allows weights, as in your example *`[3, 3, 2] , [.375, .375, .25]`*

```
import random

options = [
    "https://media.giphy.com/media/vgPDmpQsQsjug/giphy.gif",
    "http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/676/205/57b.gif",
    "Bye"
]

print(random.choice(options))
print(*random.choices(options, [.375, .375, .25]))
```

> ```
> http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/676/205/57b.gif
> https://media.giphy.com/media/vgPDmpQsQsjug/giphy.gif
> ```